# Highcharts pannig and zooming out of limits

Tags: highcharts, zooming, pan

I would like to use Highcharts and I need to pan/zoom outside displayed data.
I need to pan/zoom (on both sides) outside the loaded data to load new data from my database.

[What I want to do with Highcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPzEu.gif)

Currently I'm using the Plotly graph, but its not handling touch devices (pinch zooming) at all.

thanks,
s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `min` and `max` properties for `xAxis`:

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false,
    min: -999,
    max: 1999
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rx4ewu7n/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.max

Comment: Thanks! But still, without the bottom scroll bar I'm not able to pan/zoom outside loaded data.

Comment: Hi @Stepan, You can overwrite `pan` method and set `paddedMin` and `paddedMax` variables: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/536ysjLq/

Comment: Thank you sir! Its really working! And wouldn't you know how to do the same with zooming, be able to zoom out of the displayed data?

Comment: You just need to set `zoomType: 'x'`, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r7tyo9bk/